# BackHandler 'hardwareBackPress working only Single time | React native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, onbackpressed

I need to handle the Back Press on Android Device, but my BackHandler is only working Single time.

Here is my Code Snippet -

```
 componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
    }

        handleBackPress = () => {

            console.log("handleBackPress Called on RootMenuView : current View ? : " + this.state.mainView);

            if (this.state.mainView === "Main"){
                return false;
            } else{
                this.state.mainView = "Main";
                this.forceUpdate();
                return true;
            }

        }
```

I need to handle this on Menu View, since i need to show the default component on back press of other components.

Answer (score 2):

```
 componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
   }
   componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
 }

    handleBackPress = () => {

        console.log("handleBackPress Called on RootMenuView : current View ? : " + this.state.mainView);

        if (this.state.mainView === "Main"){
            return false;
        } else{
             //not this
            //this.state.mainView = "Main";
            // use this
           this.setState({mainView: "Main"})
            this.forceUpdate();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond, but on second time the listener is not working, i mean like this method `handleBackPress` is not being called :(

Comment: when you click on the back button what happens? Do you leave the component? Because if you leave the component componentWillUnmount runs and remove the registered listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      if(props.navigation.isFocused()){
      Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to go back?", [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () =>console.log("hi"),
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
      ]);
      return false;
    };}

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      backAction
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);
```